# Paxos algorithm, accept phase

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

From the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)

> If a Proposer receives enough Promises from a Quorum of Acceptors, it needs to set a value v to its proposal. If any Acceptors had previously accepted any proposal, then they'll have sent their values to the Proposer, who now must set the value of its proposal, v, to the value associated with the highest proposal number reported by the Acceptors, let's call it z. If none of the Acceptors had accepted a proposal up to this point, then the Proposer may choose the value it originally wanted to propose, say x.
>
> The Proposer sends an Accept message, (n, v), to a Quorum of Acceptors with the chosen value for its proposal, v, and the proposal number n (which is the same as the number contained in the Prepare message previously sent to the Acceptors). So, the Accept message is either (n, v=z) or, in case none of the Acceptors previously accepted a value, (n, v=x).

Question. If a Proposer received from an Acceptor number higher from Proposer number (Proposer sent number=2, but received from Acceptor number=3). Current a Proposer value is not outdated? (because number=3 already exist in Acceptors). Why a Proposer must send value z (value z already exist into Acceptors)?